# SQL Dynamic Pivot - Duplicate aggregation type, multiple aggregation fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that looks like the following and would like to pivot it.
See screenshots and below data example
[Input Data and Desired Output][1]

The Contact Type column is somewhat dynamic in that it can contain multiple values for each customer and each customer will not have the same number of contact types.

It is also unique in that it can contain multiple records of the same ContactType with different data values.

### Data

[Current Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIUTg.png)

[Desired Pivot Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKx85.png)

### SQL Code

```
SELECT
   [Acct],
   IsNull([0],'') as 'Phone',
   IsNull([1],'') as 'Phone',
   IsNull([2],'') as 'Telefax',
   IsNull([3],'') as 'CellPhone',
   IsNull([4],'') as 'Email',
   IsNull([5],'') as 'PurchaseEmail'

FROM (  
  SELECT 
    vt.AccountNum as 'Acct',
    dcadr.phone as 'Phone',
    dcadr.email as 'Email',
    ECommunicationTypeId as 'Type',  
    ECommunicationTypeId as 'Type2'  
 
  FROM DirPartyECommunicationRela2608 dMap 
    inner join DirECommunicationAddress dcAdr on dMap.ValuesRecId = dcAdr.RecId
    inner join VendTable vt on vt.PartyId = dMap.PartyId
        
  WHERE GETDATE() between dMap.ValidFromDateTime and dMap.ValidToDateTime
) Selections

PIVOT (
  MIN ([Phone]) 
  FOR [Type] in ([0],[1],[2],[3])
) pvtPhone

PIVOT (
  MIN ([Email]) 
  FOR [Type2] in ([4],[5])
) pvtEmail

ORDER BY [Acct]
```

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you. if you awnt to supply sample data, do so as DDL and DML statements, or at least as well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table.

Comment: pivot is great for aggregating one thing. As soon as you need two, it's time for more verbose conditional aggregation (`MAX CASE ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Since your communications data already appears to unpivoted in the `DirECommunicationAddress` table you can make use of that to perform your query with a single pivot operation, e.g.:

```sql
/*
 * Data setup
 */
create table dbo.VendTable (
  AccountNum int,
  PartyID int
);
insert dbo.VendTable(AccountNum, PartyID) values
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 3);

create table dbo.DirECommunicationAddress (
  RecId int,
  ECommunicationTypeId int,
  Phone varchar(20),
  Email varchar(50)
);
insert dbo.DirECommunicationAddress (RecId, ECommunicationTypeId, Phone, Email) values
  (1, 0, '888-888-8888', null),
  (2, 2, '888-888-8889', null),
  (3, 3, null, 'joe@joe.com'),
  (4, 0, '888-111-1111', null),
  (5, 1, '503-123-1234', null),
  (6, 2, '971-123-1234', null),
  (7, 5, null, 'ar@company.com'),
  (8, 0, '609-123-1234', null),
  (9, 2, '888-123-1234', null),
  (10, 4, null, 'jane@janeco.com'),
  (11, 5, null, 'ar@janeco.com');

create table dbo.DirPartyECommunicationRela2608 (
  PartyId int,
  ValuesRecId int,
  ValidFromDateTime date default '1900-01-01',
  ValidToDateTime date default '2100-01-01'
);
insert dbo.DirPartyECommunicationRela2608 (PartyId, ValuesRecId) values
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (2, 4),
  (2, 5),
  (2, 6),
  (2, 7),
  (3, 8),
  (3, 9),
  (3, 10),
  (3, 11);
/*
 * Example pivot query
 */
SELECT
   [Acct] as [Customer],
   isnull([Phone], '') as [Phone],
   isnull([Phone2], '') as [Phone2],
   isnull([Fax], '') as [Fax],
   isnull([Cell Phone], '') as [Cell Phone],
   isnull([Email], '') as [Email],
   isnull([Remit-email], '') as [Remit-email]
FROM (  
  SELECT 
    vt.AccountNum as 'Acct',
    CommunicationTypeMap.CommunicationType,
    case
      when ECommunicationTypeId in (0, 1, 2, 3) then dcadr.Phone
      when ECommunicationTypeId in (4, 5) then dcadr.Email
    end as CommunicationValue
  FROM DirPartyECommunicationRela2608 dMap 
    inner join DirECommunicationAddress dcAdr on dMap.ValuesRecId = dcAdr.RecId
    inner join VendTable vt on vt.PartyId = dMap.PartyId
  join (values
      (0, N'Phone'),
      (1, N'Phone2'),
      (2, N'Fax'),
      (3, N'Cell Phone'),
      (4, N'Email'),
      (5, N'Remit-email')
  ) CommunicationTypeMap(Id, CommunicationType) on CommunicationTypeMap.Id=ECommunicationTypeId
  WHERE GETDATE() between dMap.ValidFromDateTime and dMap.ValidToDateTime
) Selections

PIVOT (
  MIN ([CommunicationValue]) 
  FOR [CommunicationType] in ([Phone], [Phone2], [Fax], [Cell Phone], [Email], [Remit-email])
) pvt
ORDER BY [Acct]
```

Which results in...

| Customer | Phone | Phone2 | Fax | Cell Phone | Email | Remit-email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 888-888-8888 |  | 888-888-8889 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 888-111-1111 | 503-123-1234 | 971-123-1234 |  |  | ar@company.com |
| 3 | 609-123-1234 |  | 888-123-1234 |  | jane@janeco.com | ar@janeco.com |